# alternative of for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

```
cell_support_xyz <- function(level, zero)
{
  for(i in 1:level[1]){
    for(j in 1:level[2]){
      for(k in 1:level[3]){
        cat("cell (", i, ", ", j, ", ", k,") --> support set = (", 
            +!(i == zero[1]), ", ", +!(j == zero[2]), ", ", +!(k == zero[3]), ")\n", sep = "")
        
      }      
    }
  }
}


#Example 1
l<-c(2,3,2)
z<-c(1,1,1)
> cell_support_xyz(l,z)

cell (1, 1, 1) --> support set = (0, 0, 0)
cell (1, 1, 2) --> support set = (0, 0, 1)
cell (1, 2, 1) --> support set = (0, 1, 0)
cell (1, 2, 2) --> support set = (0, 1, 1)
cell (1, 3, 1) --> support set = (0, 1, 0)
cell (1, 3, 2) --> support set = (0, 1, 1)
cell (2, 1, 1) --> support set = (1, 0, 0)
cell (2, 1, 2) --> support set = (1, 0, 1)
cell (2, 2, 1) --> support set = (1, 1, 0)
cell (2, 2, 2) --> support set = (1, 1, 1)
cell (2, 3, 1) --> support set = (1, 1, 0)
cell (2, 3, 2) --> support set = (1, 1, 1)
```

The above code works just fine. But I want to avoid **for** loop. Here I used 3 for loops (because the length of both argument vectors is 3). If the length of vectors increases or decreases the function won't work (I need to adjust for loops accordingly); which is why I want to replace for-loop with some efficient alternative that works for any length. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to remove the `for` loop and making the solution flexible enough for any length input.

We use `expand.grid` to create all possible combinations of `level` and use `apply` rowwise to create a string to print.

```
cell_support_xyz <- function(level, zero) {
  tmp <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(level, seq))
  abc <- apply(tmp, 1, function(x) 
               cat(sprintf('cell (%s) --> support set = (%s)\n', 
                   toString(x), toString(+(x != zero)))))
}

l<-c(2,3,2)
z<-c(1,1,1)

cell_support_xyz(l, z)
#cell (1, 1, 1) --> support set = (0, 0, 0)
#cell (2, 1, 1) --> support set = (1, 0, 0)
#cell (1, 2, 1) --> support set = (0, 1, 0)
#cell (2, 2, 1) --> support set = (1, 1, 0)
#cell (1, 3, 1) --> support set = (0, 1, 0)
#cell (2, 3, 1) --> support set = (1, 1, 0)
#cell (1, 1, 2) --> support set = (0, 0, 1)
#cell (2, 1, 2) --> support set = (1, 0, 1)
#cell (1, 2, 2) --> support set = (0, 1, 1)
#cell (2, 2, 2) --> support set = (1, 1, 1)
#cell (1, 3, 2) --> support set = (0, 1, 1)
#cell (2, 3, 2) --> support set = (1, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little bit on this, since this is new to me. specially **sprintf** ```function(x) 
    cat(sprintf('cell (%s) --> support set = (%s)\n', 
                toString(x), toString(+(x != zero))))```

Comment: `toString` combines the value of `x` and gives one comma-separated string. See `x <- c(1, 0, 1)` and `toString(x)`. `%s` is placeholder where we put the value of `toString(x)` for each row in `tmp` and same for `toString(+(x != zero))`. Run this for one example, `sprintf('cell (%s) --> support set = (%s)\n', toString(x), toString(+(x != z)))` which might help to understand where `x` is `x <- c(1, 0, 1)` and `z` from your post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in 2 steps:

```
l<-c(2,3,2)
z<-c(1,1,1)

cells <- expand.grid(lapply(l, seq))

t(apply(cells, 1, function(x) 1L*!(x == z)))
```

`cells` contains all the combinations. If the order matters, you can simply reorder it:

```
cells <- dplyr::arrange(cells, Var1, Var2, Var3)
```

Then, for each row (`apply(,1,)`) you can use `==` which is already vectorized to compare the entire row to the entire `z` vector.

Multiplying by `1L` makes it integer, same as `+`.